# Google app engine - Not working?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
 def get(self):
  self.response.write('test')

app=webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

This just keeps giving me an error, i have no idea...

Comment: Can you include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost there, there is just one problem. You inherit it from webapp2 but there is no webapp2.

Add this to your code: `import webapp2`

Comment: what makes you think its an import error rather than an indentation issue?